# Why does re.search('\.', '.') not return None?

Tags: python, string, python-re

```
import re
```

I want to check if a string contains a full stop. I know I can do

```
>>> re.search(re.escape('.'), '.')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='.'>
```

or, equivalently,

```
>>> re.search('\\.', '.')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='.'>
```

I can also use a raw string and do

```
>>> re.search(r'\.', '.')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='.'>
```

But why does

```
>>> re.search('\.', '.')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='.'>
```

also work? Does Python implicitly convert it to a raw string under the hood or something?

Comment: because `\\.` is basically a `.` and it is matching the `.` on the right hand side

Comment: because `'\.' == '\\.' == r'\.'` those are three string literal expressions that create the exact same string. Note, it doesn't convert anything implicitly to a raw string, that doesn't really make sense, a raw string isn't a *type* of string, it is a kind of literal expression that produces a string object. The same kind produced by other string literals

Comment: `'\.' == '\\.'` I find this surprising, but it makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Python implicitly convert it to a raw string under the hood or something?

`\.` is not a [valid escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), so Python implicitly assumes an actual `\` character (aka `\\.`) and triggers a `DeprecationWarning`, but since those are silenced by default you just get the "working version".

Here's what happens if you enable `DeprecationWarning`s (well all warnings technically):

```sh
❯ python -q -Wd
>>> '\.'
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \.
'\\.'
```

Also FWIW a "raw string" is not a type, it's just a syntactic convenience. "raw" and "non-raw" strings both result in string objects, they just change how the string literal is *parsed*.